# some of persons or groups used in permission conditions/actions are missing workflow

Tags: workflow, permissions

I have created a workflow which has a consolidation stage which sets permissions for the form depending on who created it. For the most part it works but for a few people it gives the error occurred 'message' in the list column for that workflow.
Checking the logs I found this

```
System.ArgumentException: Some of persons or groups used in permission conditions/actions are missing     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.PermissionsHelper.ConvertUsers(ArrayList users, List`1 userNames, List`1 groupIds)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.PermissionsHelper.GetPermissionsFromParams(ArrayList users, ArrayList roles)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.PermissionsHelper.ReplacePermissions(IListItemByKeyService hostInterface, WorkflowContext __Context, ArrayList Users, ArrayList Roles, String ListId, SPItemKey itemKey)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WithKey.ReplaceListItemPermissionsActivity.DoUpdate(ActivityExecutionContext provider)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WaitForDocumentUnlockActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext...  
01/18/2016 14:25:36.46* w3wp.exe (0x25FC)                           0x3F94  SharePoint Foundation           Workflow Infrastructure         98d4    Unexpected  ... executionContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WithKey.ReplaceListItemPermissionsActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext provider)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(Activity activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()
```

I have tried googling but cant really find anything. Does anyone have any ideas or what the error is or what I can try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that within the **Set Permissions** module, that you are not removing the already existing permissions on that item (breaking inheritance). The list item permissions will most likely inherit from the List to begin with.